# How to create an Ember computed property that adds 1 to a property?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, computed-properties

I'm just learning Ember and I'm a bit confused about computed properties. Everything in the guides uses strings, like a computed property that creates a full name out of a first and last name, etc. Anyway, I'm confused about how to use integers because it seems like the syntax almost demands the use of strings.

As an example, I have a property on my controller called `count`.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  count: 0,

  counter: Ember.computed('count', function() {
    var num = `${this.get('count')}`;
    var newNum = parseInt(num) + 1;
    this.set('count', newNum);
    return this.get('count');
  })
});
```

I know this code is really bad, I'm just trying to illustrate what I'm trying to do and failing at. Why does `Ember.computed` take a string as its first parameter?

And why do I have to use a string in `this.get` and `this.set` when I'm working with an integer, not a string? I have to manually parse the int or else it returns a string, why is it converting my count property into a string?

Anyway, in the ember inspector when I run

`$E.get('count')`

it does successfully add 1, but fails to continue to add 1, which makes me think its not updating the actual `count` property.

Thanks very much. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you considered using `Ember.Object.incrementProperty()`, [link to Ember API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_incrementProperty)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I set up a [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c9c2219b03e2c0133d8c) based on your code. I'll try to address each of your questions:

You can think of an `Ember.Object` as a wrapper around `{}`. All `Ember.Object` keys are Strings, because `{}` [keys are strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3608246/1067145).

For each property stored on an `Ember.Object`, that property is a value with some String as its key. To look up that value, you have to provide the "path" or "location" of the value, as given by the key (just like a hash table). This is why you need to specify a string in `get` and `set`.

Values can be any type in Javascript, not just strings. Take a look at the [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c9c2219b03e2c0133d8c) I posted, and open up your console. In your code, `num` is a string because you've wrapped it in an ES6 template string, which is converting the value of `this.get('count')`.

---

`Ember.computed` was designed to render data into templates. It's important to understand that:

- It's *lazy*
- It caches the result of the computation.
- A Computed Property will *only* recompute if one or more of the properties it depends on changes.

When you call `Ember.computed`, you first pass in any number of strings. Each string is a path to a value (on an `Ember.Object`) that your CP "depends" on.

Because CPs are lazy, `'counter'` will only be computed when you access it in your code, or in a template. If `'count'` were to change, the cached value of `'counter'` would be forgotten. The *next* time `'counter'` were accessed, it would recompute.

In this case, the `'counter'` CP function only runs once, because `'count'` never changes. This is why you only observe one addition.