# Using multiple ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th ng-repeat="header in headers">{{header}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="table in tables">
      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="header in headers">{{$parent.table.header}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a json array retrieved from a server. First ng-repeat: 'headers' contain keys in that json array which i extracted. It works fine in all cases. 
Second ng-repeat: 'tables' contain the json array received. What i am trying to do is for each element of json array, find data by providing key values. 
here is my multiple ng-repeat code. This doesn't work, no data is printed in the table but if i change `{{$parent.table.header}}` to `{{$parent.table}}` or `{{header}}` i can see data in the table.
The problem is `{{$parent.table.header}}` how can i do it correctly ?

Comment: it isn't clear what you are trying to output here.  Can you provide more information, specifically what your data looks like, and what you expect to see in the output?

Comment: post your code in plunkr will be use full to resolve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `$parent.table[header]` - because `header` is already a string.

Comment: that worked...but table is not an array, it is a json string. so i can access json like this ? i thought i can access it only by 'dot'

Comment: Well keys are properties - but when looping over object's keys they defined as strings - then you can access them with ["STRING GOES HERE"];
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608246/what-is-the-type-of-keys-in-javascript