# Do JSON Objects which contain custom keys as objects work?

Tags: javascript, json, nodes

From what I've learned, javascript allows any type to a value of an key inside an object like:

```
{
  key1: "string",
  key2: ["list"],
  key3: 123,
  key4: { name: "string embedded in an object in another object"}
}
```

But it only allows certain certain types for the keys like string and integers:
{
  "string": "string",
  123: "integer"
}

I came across this when I wrote the below code this and the key ended up being:  `[object Object]`

```
let a = {}
let b = {}

b.name = {name: "name"}

a[b.name] = "value"

console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
```

Result from above:

```
{"[object Object]":"value"}
```

So what types are allowed for keys in objects in js??
And why does it show the key as [object Object]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keys in Javascript objects can only be strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066846/keys-in-javascript-objects-can-only-be-strings)

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing two different concepts. JSON and JavaScript objects–although similar–are not the same. You can read about [the difference between JSON and the Object Literal Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation).

- [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) has a limited grammar and properties can only be strings.
- A [JavaScript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Objects)'s "key value is either a String or a Symbol value". You can find more information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066846/keys-in-javascript-objects-can-only-be-strings).

> And why does it show the key as [object Object]?

Because keys can only be strings or symbols. Any other value is coerced to a string (e.g. by calling the value's `toString` method if available). `({}).toString()` returns "[object Object]"`.

If you want to use objects as keys, you can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Answer (score 1):

If you try running this it will output `value` and if you print the key type it will be `string`

```
let a = {}
let b = {}

b.name = {name: "name"}

a[b.name] = "value"

console.log(a['[object Object]'])
for (key in a) {
    console.log(typeof key);
    //-> "string"
}
```

Javascript makes the key a string before saving it.

Similar question has been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3608275/12703377

Answer (score 1):

The key of a object can be only a string or a symbol. When you put an object into `[]` operator, the string representation of that object is used as a key.

```
let a = {}
let b = {
    toString: function(){return "B string representation"}
}
a['attribute'] = 'value'
a[b] = 'value'
a[2] = 'value'
Object.keys(a)
```

result

```
(3) ["2", "attribute", "B string representation"]
```

Off your question... looking at your code, what you probably want to do is

```
let a = {}
let b = {}
b.name = "name"
a[b.name] = "value"
console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
```