# How to add instance of a class into a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a class as shown below

```
class test{
    constructor(x){
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

And I have created an instance of this class and stored into a variable `temp`.

```
let temp = new test(10);
```

And I also have an object where I wish to put `temp`.

```
let obj = {};
obj[temp] = true;
```

But when I see `obj`, it does not contain what I expected, it contains

```
{[object Object]: true}
[object Object]: true
__proto__: Object
```

I am unable to figure out where am I going wrong, what does `object Object` stand for, any help would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

If I create another instance of the object `let temp2 = new test(10);` and check `temp2 in obj` it returns `true` and also `temp in obj` returns `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[object Object]` is the text representation for objects in JavaScript, which certain printer functions will print out instead of traversing the object.

That said, you can't expect to be able to use an object (e.g. "{ foo: 123 }"  as a key of another object (e.g. "foo" is the key in earlier example). It will get flattened to a string with key "object Object" as you saw, much like a printer function will do.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee apologies for my earlier answer. check my update

Comment: Ya, I also figured out that using object as a key is wrong, since it is mutable.

Answer (score 0):

Class instances are represented by objects with class functions and attributes in JS. Further read [Classes by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) I created a codesandbox to briefly illustrate that https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-wood-9fk4x?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

The datatype of what you're returning is an Object

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
obj[temp] = true;
```

You are actually putting a boolean value in to a property with its **key** being an object, which gets converted to a string. Consider if what you really want is:

```
obj['embeddedObject'] = temp;
```

Which makes more sense under `console.log(obj)`.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, An Object stores properties (key-value pairs), where: **Property keys** must be strings or symbols (usually strings) and **Values** can be of any type. For more info you can go through this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608246/what-is-the-type-of-keys-in-javascript).

In you case when you put `temp` to `obj` as a property key name, `temp.toString()` is called implicitly and by default implementation returns `"[object Object]"`. As your class **test** didn't override the `toString()` method and your created instances also **temp** and **temp2** didn't override it, you always get default implementation return value of **toString()**. Therefore you get same output for both `temp2 in obj` and `temp in obj`.

Answer (score 0):

Object declarations with the `{}` are a shorthand syntax that hides the [object prototype](https://javascript.info/native-prototypes#object-prototype):

```
let obj = {}; // what you wrote
let obj = new Object() // what your JS interpreter sees
obj.prototype.object // what your JS interpreter creates
```

This is very similar to using the `class` shorthand syntax. [But `class` is a double abstraction](https://javascript.info/class#what-is-a-class), hiding the fact it is really creating a function and that it's doing so with the [function prototype](https://javascript.info/function-prototype):

```
// what you wrote
class test{
    constructor(x){
        this.x = x;
    }
}

// what your JS interpreter creates
test.prototype.constructor
```

So when you are logging `obj` and you get `[object Object]`, your JS interpreter is telling you that you have created an object of prototype Object. You're confusing yourself with `test`, just stop with that - they are in different scopes and don't mean the same thing. Learn prototypes first.

### JS Under the Hood

The thing to remember is that Javascript is an object-oriented language but **does not use class-based inheritance like most other OOP**. Javascript uses [prototype inheritance](https://javascript.info/prototype-inheritance). When you [instantiate a class in JS](https://javascript.info/class#what-is-a-class), it's not really a class in the classical programming sense.

Just to reiterate, your JS `class` actually gets defined as a function. Try it out:

```
console.log(typeof test) //output: function
```

There's more to it though. Let's say we extend your example a bit further with another method:

```
class test{
  constructor(x){
    this.x = x;
  }

  // Custom method
  outputX() {
    console.log(this.x)
  }
}
```

What have we actually done? As mentioned above, the JS interpreter will read your class and leverage the [function prototype](https://javascript.info/function-prototype) to create it. So what makes this different than just defining a function?

Because you used `class`, the function prototype automatically assigns a constructor method to your new `test` prototype. All other custom methods - like `outputX` that I added in - get added onto the `test` prototype.

```
// All valid
test.prototype.constructor
test.prototype.outputX
test.prototype.whateverMethodYouMake
```