# How to use regex as a mapping key for object

Tags: angular, regex, typescript, mapping

I'm trying to map object with keys so that I can easily return them.
I can either get a string or RegExp which is the problem, setting the key as a string is easy.

This is how I set key for object when route is string, but the problem is that I cannot set regex as a key, it needs to be either a number or a string.

```
private nodesByRoute: { [key: string]: NavbarItemNode } = {};

this.nodesByRoute[node.route] = node;
```

So I would imagine the solution would look something like this:

```
private nodesByRoute: { [key: string | RegExp]: NavbarItemNode } = {};
```

My implementation is that I get a route string, let's say /category/items and if it matches it will return the node like this:

```
return this.nodesByRoute[routerLink];
```

But I also need this to work with regex because I can get something like this: `/items/60`.
So I get `items/` and the number of the item, thats why I need regex as a key.

Also I think I will also need logic when trying match the keys with my route.
The route will always be a string but the key might be regex so I don't think this will work:

```
return this.nodesByRoute[routerLink];
```

Comment: I don't think that this is possible because JavaScript only allows for keys of type `string`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608246/what-is-the-type-of-keys-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want in your case.

But if you want to use something as a key besides string and number, you can try `Map`.

```ts
const nodesByRoute: Map<RegExp, NavbarItemNode> = new Map<RegExp, NavbarItemNode>();
```

However, there is a caveat. If you use a literal `RegExp` to get the value, it will not work.

```ts
const m = new Map<RegExp, string>();
m.set(/ab.*/, "Hello World");
console.log(m.get(/ab.*/)); // undefined
```

Because the different literal `RegExp` will be treated as different `RegExp` instances, using a non-primitive object as a key of a `Map` means using the object's reference as a key. So the code below will work.

```ts
const m = new Map<RegExp, string>();
const regexKey: RegExp = /ab.*/;
m.set(regexKey, "Hello World");
console.log(m.get(regexKey)); // "Hello World"
```

When you are trying to do so, it also means you need to manage all of those `RegExp` keys. That may not be what you want to take the time to do.

And I think the thing you really want to is such like:

```ts
const m = new Map<RegExp, string>();
m.set(/ab.*/, "Hello World");
console.log(m.get('abc')); // undefined
```

Again, the string `'abc'` will not automatically match the `RegExp` key. That's the part you need to do some work.

In my opinion, you can try to create a method that implements the logic of different route patterns checking, then return the value you want with easily call the method as below:

```ts
let node = this.nodesByRoute(routerLink);
```

Comment: Thank you, yes my plan is for it work like the last solution you gave, so I guess I'll need to play with the logic a bit when returning the value.